# Magento 2 Static Content Deploy Ignores Frech Locale

Tags: magento, locale, translation, magento2, language-packs

When I run `php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy`

Only **en_US** folder is created in below folder
*`/var/www/html/pub/static/frontend/Magento/blank/`*

**fr_FR** folder is not created until I run `php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy fr_FR`

can someone tell me why this happens?

Answer (score 0):

There seems a Magento bug raised for this and the fix will be available in 2.2. Please read this discussion for more information

https://github.com/magento/magento2/issues/4229

Comment: the issue seems to be persistent even in the 2.1.7 release, have you worked on other locales except en_US ?

Comment: Yes, it exists in 2.1.9 as well. They have merged fix to 2.2. Yes, Most of the products I worked in are en_AU based and en_UK. So, I used locale as inline parameter. And it improves the performance as well

Comment: Thanks, looks like I have to run deployment for each locale manually then :(

Comment: No, you can deploy multiple locales at once php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy fr_FR en_US en_AU

Comment: I mean, only `php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy` is not enough I guess, however it created the fr_FR folder some times but doesn't creates all the files